# Usage of the expression « pour ne pas la nommer » compared to its English lookalike « I'm naming no names »

Tags: sens, usage

> Si vous voulez bien m’aider à retrouver quelqu'un ? Sophie **pour ne pas la nommer**. Elle a été mon premier amour.

Je crois constater deux différences majeures entre « pour ne pas la nommer » et l'expression anglaise qui, à première vue, semble s'en rapprocher le plus : « I'm naming no names » ou « who shall remain anonymous ». Enfin, si on prend le sens de « pour ne pas la nommer » au pied de la lettre, du moins.

1. Avec l’expression « I'm naming no names », l’identité d’une personne que l’on a en tête ne sera pas dévoilée ; elle est bel et bien censée demeurer dans l'anonymat.

   Quant à « pour ne pas la nommer », en revanche, je me demande si elle est invariablement utilisée de manière ironique quand on vient, en fait, tout juste de prononcer son nom ? S’agit-il toujours d’une fausse négation, d’une figure de rhétorique ?
2. Quand on dit « I hate to name names, but ... » en anglais, on estime que la personne en question est impliquée dans une quelconque activité immorale, d'où la nécessité de révéler son nom.

   Pour ce qui est de « pour ne pas la nommer », s'emploie-t-elle également dans un contexte tel que celui-ci, dénué de la moindre once de connotation négative ?

Comment: A cool question to which I have nothing substantive to contribute, but I can say that the (literal) English versions (your "I'm naming no names" and "who shall remain anonymous" [as well as "Without naming names"]) is in fact often said with a "wink and a nod toward" [or even with a silent finger pointed to or an arm around the shoulder of) the unmentioned, yet clearly identified, party.

Comment: @PapaPoule Hi. Indeed. These English expressions, as sarcastic as they may be, retain the anonymous aspect at the end of the day, in which they stand in stark contrast to « pour ne pas la nommer », I think. After all, we say "Mr. you-know-who, who shall remain anonymous", but we don't say "Sophie, who shall remain anonymous" or "I'm naming no names, but Sophie ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. ***Pour ne pas le/la nommer*** est toujours employé de façon [ironique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironie), immédiatement précédé ou suivi du nom de la personne ou de la chose en question.
2. Cette expression peut s'employer sans aucune connotation négative.

Comment: Hi. "***Ce jeune homme que j'ai rencontré hier soir*** pour ne pas le nommer" : Alors, cette tournure ne s'entend pas du tout,  c’est ça ?

Comment: Oui, cette phrase n'est pas du tout idiomatique. Elle est de plus ambiguë car on a l'impression que c'est *hier soir* qu'il ne faut pas nommer.

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit d'une pure figure de style et de rhétorique, la **prétérition** pour ne pas la citer.
[Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9t%C3%A9rition) en donne de nombreux exemples, les formes pouvant être diverses.